# ItunesConnect processing app forever

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I was uploading my application (v1.3 build 105) and I had some internet issue that I cannot process to upload it.
After that I tried to upload it once again. But build 105 was never available. I've changed application build number to 106 and upload it once again.

[image]

And now I have problem with internal testing, because I cannot select newest build (build 105 is still processing).

[image]

Do anyone had similar issue?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been through the same experience few times.

We upload builds with iTunes Connect and it can fail due to any reason, maybe the network etc.

It still appears in the iTunes build list with `processing label` as you have mentioned.

Then, you have to upload a fresh build with a new build number.

**Sometimes, the new build takes 2 hours, even up to 6-8 hours to get listed for testing, and then this false "processing" labeled entry gets cleared.**

I would suggest waiting for a while, and then you will be able to test your new uploaded build.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this issue happened with me too. Actually the problem is the uploading process did not finished and aborted due to slow internet connection. But meanwhile uploading, it creates a record in the itunesconnect whose processing starts at certain part of the app finished uploading.

But since the complete app is not uploaded. Therefore it remains in the processing state.

I am sorry, you will have to wait for some more time and this new build 106 will be considered and the older one will be removed from it.

Answer (score 1):

**Just a note-**

Don't forget to refresh the page or logout and login again to see the correct status of your build. Simply switching tabs on itunesconnect won't help in many cases.

If possible try to clear cache/use different browser instance just to make sure that the status is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new version of my app 1.3.1 (build 107) and now everything looks right, I can select build for testing etc.